# Unable to run Poincare Embeddings example to get hierarchical representation

Tags: python, hierarchical-data, word-embedding

I'm trying to replicate [Poincaré Embeddings for Learning Hierarchical Representations](https://papers.nips.cc/paper/7213-poincare-embeddings-for-learning-hierarchical-representations) present on [Github](https://github.com/facebookresearch/poincare-embeddings) by Facebook Research. But I'm unable to run `example.sh` to embed the mammals subtree in the reconstruction setting.

**OS**: Ubuntu 16.04, Using **Anaconda** 4.3.30, **Python** 3.6.5, **Pytorch** 0.4.0

**Command**: `NHTHREDS=2 ./example.sh`

**Error Log:**

```
Using 2 threads
slurp: objects=1181, edges=6541
Indexing data
json_conf: {"distfn": "poincare", "dim": 5, "lr": 0.3, "batchsize": 10, "negs": 50}
Burnin: lr=0.003
'Traceback (most recent call last):\n  File "/home/harman/anaconda3/envs/pytorch-venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/torch/utils/data/dataloader.py", line 57, in _worker_loop\n    samples = collate_fn([dataset[i] for i in batch_indices])\n  File "/home/harman/anaconda3/envs/pytorch-venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/torch/utils/data/dataloader.py", line 57, in <listcomp>\n    samples = collate_fn([dataset[i] for i in batch_indices])\n  File "/home/harman/harman_workspace/poincare-embeddings/model.py", line 185, in __getitem__\n    if n not in self._weights[t]:\nKeyError: tensor(491)\n'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/harman/harman_workspace/poincare-embeddings/train.py", line 19, in train_mp
    train(model, data, optimizer, opt, log, rank, queue)
  File "/home/harman/harman_workspace/poincare-embeddings/train.py", line 46, in train
    for inputs, targets in loader:
  File "/home/harman/anaconda3/envs/pytorch-venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/torch/utils/data/dataloader.py", line 286, in __next__
    return self._process_next_batch(batch)
  File "/home/harman/anaconda3/envs/pytorch-venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/torch/utils/data/dataloader.py", line 307, in _process_next_batch
    raise batch.exc_type(batch.exc_msg)
KeyError: 'Traceback (most recent call last):\n  File "/home/harman/anaconda3/envs/pytorch-venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/torch/utils/data/dataloader.py", line 57, in _worker_loop\n    samples = collate_fn([dataset[i] for i in batch_indices])\n  File "/home/harman/anaconda3/envs/pytorch-venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/torch/utils/data/dataloader.py", line 57, in <listcomp>\n    samples = collate_fn([dataset[i] for i in batch_indices])\n  File "/home/harman/harman_workspace/poincare-embeddings/model.py", line 185, in __getitem__\n    if n not in self._weights[t]:\nKeyError: tensor(491)\n'
'Traceback (most recent call last):\n  File "/home/harman/anaconda3/envs/pytorch-venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/torch/utils/data/dataloader.py", line 57, in _worker_loop\n    samples = collate_fn([dataset[i] for i in batch_indices])\n  File "/home/harman/anaconda3/envs/pytorch-venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/torch/utils/data/dataloader.py", line 57, in <listcomp>\n    samples = collate_fn([dataset[i] for i in batch_indices])\n  File "/home/harman/harman_workspace/poincare-embeddings/model.py", line 185, in __getitem__\n    if n not in self._weights[t]:\nKeyError: tensor(491)\n'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/harman/harman_workspace/poincare-embeddings/train.py", line 19, in train_mp
    train(model, data, optimizer, opt, log, rank, queue)
  File "/home/harman/harman_workspace/poincare-embeddings/train.py", line 46, in train
    for inputs, targets in loader:
  File "/home/harman/anaconda3/envs/pytorch-venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/torch/utils/data/dataloader.py", line 286, in __next__
    return self._process_next_batch(batch)
  File "/home/harman/anaconda3/envs/pytorch-venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/torch/utils/data/dataloader.py", line 307, in _process_next_batch
    raise batch.exc_type(batch.exc_msg)
KeyError: 'Traceback (most recent call last):\n  File "/home/harman/anaconda3/envs/pytorch-venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/torch/utils/data/dataloader.py", line 57, in _worker_loop\n    samples = collate_fn([dataset[i] for i in batch_indices])\n  File "/home/harman/anaconda3/envs/pytorch-venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/torch/utils/data/dataloader.py", line 57, in <listcomp>\n    samples = collate_fn([dataset[i] for i in batch_indices])\n  File "/home/harman/harman_workspace/poincare-embeddings/model.py", line 185, in __getitem__\n    if n not in self._weights[t]:\nKeyError: tensor(491)\n'
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I had same errors. it's about key error as its version. 
https://github.com/facebookresearch/poincare-embeddings/issues/12

here is the solutions, they answered changing int about h,w,t
I tried but failed , and try down the version of torch 1.0.0 to 0.3.1. it's in success.

hope to solve the problems